Ubuntu 24.04 and Lenovo Thinkpad T14 suspend issues
I am running a new installation of Ubuntu noble 24.04 x86_64 (kernel 6.8.0-45-generic) on a brand new Thinkpad T14 Gen 5 (AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 8840U w/ Radeon 780M Graphics (16) @ 6.08 GHz)
The machine does not suspend properly, which I noticed after returning from work with it in my backpack, taking it out and it was hot.
While suspended the screen is in fact off, and the relevant LEDs enter a "breath" mode, indicating a suspended state, but there is an audible mechanical "tick" sound coming from where I suppose the fan is located and the laptop produces heat (gets hot if it's in a closed environment like my backpack)
At first I thought it was a "lid closed" issue, but after further experimentation turns out that it's not a lid issue, but a suspension issue; suspending from the power button has the same result
It is definitely an Ubuntu issue, since on Windows (I am dual booting) suspending works properly; tested it, no "tick" sound no heat.
Is there a known fix for this, which I could not find, or should I report it? (Should I report to Lenovo or Ubuntu?)
Thank you
P.S. for what it's worth, my Thinkpad x13 Gen 1 on ubuntu 22 has no issues with suspend.

I have the T14 gen 5 intel version, so it might be a different issue. But for me, I looked at dmesg. Apparently there's a bug in the ethernet driver related to WOL preventing standby. Disabling WOL fixed the issue for me.
# as root
cat > /etc/systemd/system/disable_wol.service <<"EOF"
[Unit]
Description=Disable Wake-on-LAN on e1000e
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp0s31f6 wol d
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable disable_wol
systemctl start disable_wol
systemctl status disable_wol
journalctl -u disable_wol


This worked for me perfectly! I have E14 gen 6 and Ubuntu 24.04 and had the same issue with standby. Thank you! You are a genious!

this fix also worked for me on a Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 6, model 21M7002VIV
Thank you @Allanrbo !
